# Why can't I reference jQuery using a script tag in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

To use jquery inside nodejs electron app. i have to install jQuery via npm and use `require('jquery')` to reference `jQuery`.

It works fine.

I need to know why i cant attach jquery like inside normal browser using script tags

`<script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script> //getting error $ not defined`

Code below using just script tags to attached jquery, its getting an error, $ is not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script>-->
        <!--var $ = require('jquery');-->
    <!--</script>-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){});
    </script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum vel, ipsum nisi laboriosam nesciunt. Asperiores dolorum tempore quia, voluptatum laborum dolore officiis velit similique amet totam in? At, neque, assumenda.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying that inside an electron app, then it is most likely the fact that the Jquery file is not in the path specified. It would most likely be located in /node_modules/Jquery/... Something like that. Try an absolute path. Alternatively, if the host computer is connected to the Internet you should be able to use the Jquery CDN.

This appears to be a known issue with a work around in Electron,

[Here #254](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/254)

Comment: It is attaching successfully. Debug in chrome dev tools. Also tried CDN. Still not working

Comment: Is "window.jquery" defined?

Comment: window.jQuery :  "jQuery" not defined

Comment: Should be all lowercase, no?

Comment: "jQuery sees that its running in a CommonJS environment and expects to be used as such". Thank you!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

As already noted, jQuery tries to be smart and find out if it's in a browser or a node.js environment. In a browser it would define `$` and `jQuery` but in a node.js environment it tries to export its main object by assigning it to `module.exports`.

As the renderer process has node.js (and `module`) available jQuery incorrectly assumes that it was included with `require`.

So as a workaround you can use something like this:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery = $ = module.exports </script>
```